# jQuery's $.proxy vs var self - The common way to preserve the context of `this`

Tags: jquery

What is the common way to preserve the context of `this`?
What is faster? What would you prefer?

1. $.proxy(...)

   ```
   $('a').on('click', $.proxy(function() {
       this.close();
   }, this));
   ```
2. var self

   ```
   var self = this;

   $('a').on('click', function() {
       self.close();
   });
   ```

Comment: My personal statistic stays it's about fifty-fifty. In all seriousness: Choose one and stick with it. FYI, `$.proxy` is the same as the native `.bind` method of functions.

Comment: Faster how? In terms of execution, you'd have to [benchmark it](http://jsperf.com). What would I prefer? I'd go with the second option because it's just more readable to me.

Comment: Personally I like `self` more, a) because it's slightly faster, b) it's more readable and c) because you probably would cache `this` in a local variable anyway (if used repeatedly) after proxy it to the anonymous function.

Comment: It is insane that this was closed. The user asked "which is faster?" In what world is that not a factual question?! In this case, the answer can be found here: http://jsperf.com/var-self-vs-proxy

Answer (score 2):

Let's start by fixing your code. You have a useless function declaration, you may use `$.proxy` as

```
$('a').on('click', $.proxy(this.close, this));
```

Now, the second solution based on `self`

- requires only basic javascript knowledge
- doesn't require jQuery
- is a little more readable, especially as you often reuse your `self` variable
- is much faster

That's probably why it's more used.

Note that when you don't have to be compatible with IE8, you may use [bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) :

```
$('a').on('click', this.close.bind(this));
```

Answer (score 1):

Both are common.

The speed in this case is not relevant. The user will not notice if the callback for the click starts after 0.01 ms. or 0.1 ms.

For the rare occasion where it would matter, I expect the variable method to be slightly faster, but you would have to benchmark it.

My personal preference varies, depending on where it's used, and what the code inside the callback does. One advantage of the variable method is that it works for nested callbacks without the need to reapply it to each level.

Comment: There's a whole other reason for choosing the more efficient way than just reaction time: if the actions starts 0.1 ms instead of 0.01 ms after click that means it has 0.09 ms more of JS execution, which on a smartphone directly results in more battery loss for the same action. Sure it's practically nothing, but it accumulates fast. Also, just for the record: 0.1 to 0.01 is still a 1000% improvement after all ;).

Comment: @Simon: You are micro optimising. If you want to optimise, there is surely other things in your code where you could save a whole lot more execution time.

Comment: True, but it's about the principle of choosing the more efficient way in general, not the actual time saving you would get in this example.

Comment: @Simon: Yes, that is a good principle when you apply it in the right place, but it's micro optimising when you apply it in the wrong place.

Comment: We could state that a bit differently and say that it isn't micro _optimizing_ if you've learned to use the faster way *from the beginning*. If we would talk about code refactoring this would actually be micro optimizing, but the OP wants to know which one of the options he should choose in his future projects and you are ignoring the argument of code efficiency (no offense).

Comment: @Simon: No, there is no difference if you write new code or refactor code, the difference is in what criteria you use to choose between implementations. If you base the choise mainly on performance where performance is not relevant, that is micro optimising.

Answer (score 0):

Choose First one. doesn't require an extra variable.